# Unir dataframes sin que aumenten los registros en Python

Tags: python, dataframe, union

Quiero unir dos dataframe. Uno tiene el nombre de **draf** en el cual tengo 14000 registros y el otro se llama **correcto** y tiene 18560 registros.

A la hora de unirlos, en mi dataframe **draf** me aumentan los registros. Solo quiero quedarme con los 14000. ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Hasta ahora estuve usando este codigo:

```
draf = pd.merge(draf, correcto, how='left')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para quedarte con solo los 14000 registros del dataframe "draf" utilizando el método pd.merge() puedes utilizar el método head(n) de pandas para seleccionar solo los primeros n registros, donde n es el número de registros que deseas mantener.

```
draf = pd.merge(draf, correcto, how='left')
draf = draf.head(14000)
```

Otra opción es utilizar slicing en el dataframe "draf"

```
draf = draf[:14000]
draf = pd.merge(draf, correcto, how='left')
```

Con esto, se esta tomando solo los primeros 14000 registros antes de hacer el merge.

Comment: Buen día, por favor lee la sección [ask] y [answer]. Las preguntas que no muestran un esfuerzo por parte del autor es mejor no responderlas hasta que sean editadas. Lo que puedes hacer es “ocultar” tu respuesta, si oprimes eliminar la respuesta se oculta y una vez que el OP haya editado la pregunta y agregado lo que ha intentado puedes recuperar la respuesta para mostrarla nuevamente.